# What referencing style is this?

Tags: citations, citation-style

My school has provided me with a referencing system but has not stated where it is from. I would prefer to use an online tool such as MyBib however, I don't know what my school's referencing system is. I have attached a screenshot below. Could anyone please help me identify it?

[image: My School's Referencing system]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not obvious what style (if indeed any) matches the examples you gave. I used the [CSL Search by Example](https://editor.citationstyles.org/searchByExample/) (CSLSE) webpage and was unable to find anything that matched exactly.

CSLSE does not list every known style but it does list thousands of different styles including many that are variants of well known, named, styles. My unsuccessful search suggest that you are unlikely to find an exactly matching style to use with MyBib, Zotero or Endnote.

If you want to try using the CSLSE site, you should use the tabs labeled "Previous" and "Next" on the linked page  to scroll through the list of publication types that CSLSE shows you until you find a publication type (e.g., Book) that matches the attributes of one of the publication types on your own list (e.g., single-authored books). Then, using the author, book title, publisher, etc. that are *shown to you by CSLSE*, together with the ***style*** in your own list, make the CSLE publication match the style you want to produce. Then click Search. CSLSE will show you a list of publication styles that match your list with regard to that specific publication type.
If you are unable to find a style that matches your needs exactly, you *could* create your own style file. Advice on how to do that is available on the website.

However, an all-round simpler solution might be to ask someone knowledgeable at your school what the style is called ... and even whether they have a style file for a particular citation manager!

Comment: "an all-round simpler solution might be to ask someone knowledgeable at your school" <-- this.